# how to change the password using ajax post in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

here email should be showing null
That's why i am getting the error 412
and my code is look like

```js
function Submit() {
var objectData =
{
"emailId": $("#emailId").val(),
"password": $("#password").val()

};

var objectDataString = JSON.stringify(objectData);
console.log(objectDataString); 
localStorage.setItem("email",$("#emailId").val());
$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "http://localhost:8080/feasthunt/common/changePassword",
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
data: objectDataString,
dataType: "json",
success: function (data,status,xhr) {
console.log(objectDataString); 
alert('success');
},
error: function () {
alert('error');
}
});
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
   
   <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
    <form role="form" id="form">
     <div class="heading"><h3 class="text-center">Change Password</h3></div>
     
     <div class="form-group" class="hidden" style="display:none">
      <label for="emailId">EmailId</label>
      <input type="emailId" class="form-control" id="emailId" placeholder="emailId" required />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Old Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Old Password" required />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">New Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password1" placeholder="New Password" required />
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Retype New Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password2" placeholder="Retype New Password" required />
     </div>
     <input class="text-center"  type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="SAVE CHANGES" onclick="Submit()">
    </form>
   </div>
  </div>
```

and above is HTML code
so how can i get email?
here the only problem is email
 tell me one thing it is possible to get the email 
so any one can answer this question

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to stringify your object, you can just send `objectData`. If you really need the parameters as JSON, you will have to assign a variable name for it, like `{data:JSON.stringify(objectData)}`.

You're sending the old password, not the new one.

And, are your running the script at `http://localhost:8080`? It may not have access to `http://localhost:8080/feasthunt/common/changePassword` from `file://` or from other domain.

Check `http://localhost:8080/feasthunt/common/changePassword` for errors. You may find useful the Network tab of the webkit's (Chrome/Opera/etc.) Inspector.